# How to make this username and password login page work

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have made this code in an attempt to create a simple 'Create a user' program which take the inputs and puts them into a csv file however I am finding that I keep getting the error `unexpected EOF while parsing` which is quite annoying. Could you please help me with this?

```
if sys.version_info < (3, 0):
    input = raw_input

def createAccount():
  username = enterUsername()
  password = enterPassword()
  appendAccount('All_users.csv', username, password, sname, year, age)

def enterUsername():
    while True:
        name = input('What is your first name?')
        sname = input('What is your surname?')
        year = input('what year are you in?')
        age = input('How old are you?')
        fName = name[:3]
        if len(userN) == 3:
            username = (fName+year)
            print(username)
        elif len(fName) != 3:
            username = (name[:3]+age)


def enterPassword():
    while True:
        password = input('Enter password: ')
        password_again = input('Confirm password: ')
        if len(password) < 5:
            print ('Your password is too short.')
        elif password != password_again:
            print ('Password and confirmation do not match.')
        else:
            return password

def appendAccount(All_users, username, password, sname, year, age):
  with open(All_users, 'a') as csv_file:
```

Comment: Use `raw_input` instead.

Comment: Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/1231450/jan

Comment: How does your enterUsername() procedure exit the loop? And shouldn't it return something?

Comment: It should but its bugging out and I want to know why

Answer (score 0):

Is end of the file?

```
def appendAccount(All_users, username, password, sname, year, age):
  with open(All_users, 'a') as csv_file:         
    ....  # here should be continuation
```